# Efficiently plotting large number of pictures on a grid in Python

Tags: image, python-3.x, matplotlib, graph, visualization

I've implemented a program that outputs a very large number of tiny images next to each other in a certain way. Currently I'm using a grid of 50x50 but I want to be able to increase this and my current code becomes really slow in that case. I've read from several people online this is because of the axis etc that is predefined when creating the grid using my current set-up. I'm using matplotlib.pyplot.subplots to create the grid. Then I remove all axis labels and whitespace between the images and then I add the images. I've heard there are better libraries to do this efficiently, but it seems they are more used for efficient line plotting, not pictures. Is there a more efficient way in Python for me to plot a grid of pictures ? Thanks a lot for the advice.

Comment: Be more precise or add sample images. Creating a grid of N images is just filling an array of dimension ```M,N,#CHANNELS```. So explain, why creating one array from all single images followed by showing/writing/encoding (e.g. png) is not enough.

Comment: First of all, some more details: 
The grid in my code is a numpy array. Each image gets a specific location in the grid by an algorithm (based on some measure of closeness) to fill up the total grid. Each image has the exact same size such that it becomes one big rectangle filled with small images.
Secondly; hmm; I will think about how to do this in the algorithm the way you say, but it sounds a bit tricky in my head; but I get your point :)

Comment: If you got an np-array ```X``` with shape ```(4,4,3)``` and an img ```y``` of size ```(2,2,3)```, ```X[:2, :2, :] = y``` would place your y in the top-left quad-block. So most of your task is just basic numpy-indexing (try to do vectorized forms like that instead of loops if performance / clean-code is wanted). Drop matplotlib and co. for one moment! You might consider using skimage, but not much of it's code is relevant to your use-case (potentially interesting: IO + view_as_blocks + resizing + color-transforms).

Comment: Yes indeed, I totally did not consider this way of doing it. Thanks a lot!